# Return attributes of pmax function output

Tags: r

I have the following numeric vectors `x` and `y`

```
x <- c(a=1,b=2,c=3)
y <- c(d=2,e=1,f=4)
```

I want to find the parallel maximum of each elements in the vectors, so I used:

```
> pmax(x,y)
a b c 
2 2 4
```

The output has the right values, however, it returns the wrong names. The documentation for `pmax` mentions that it returns the attributes of the first argument, hence the `a b c`. Is there a way of getting the names of the maximum values? The desired output is as follow:

```
d b f
2 2 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be using `max.col` for finding the index of the maximum value per each row.  For that, we need to create a matrix/data.frame by `cbind`ing the vectors ('xy') and its `names` ('nmxy'). Create a row/column index ('ij') and subset the elements of 'xy' and set the names from 'nmxy'.

```
xy <- cbind(x,y)
nmxy <- cbind(names(x), names(y))
ij <- cbind(1:nrow(xy), max.col(xy))
setNames(xy[ij], nmxy[ij])
#  d b f 
#  2 2 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
r <- pmax(x,y)
```

Simply add after the function a rename command

```
names(r)[y == r] <- names(y)[y == r]
```

If you want to be fancy, you can overload the `pmax` function to have the desired output.

```
old.pmax = pmax
pmax <- function(x,y){

  r <- old.pmax(x,y)
  names(r)[y == r] <- names(y)[y == r]
  return(r)
}
```